# Google NPM modules fails on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dialogflow-es, google-speech-api

When I tried to install google related npm modules in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it fails and the environment gets degraded. Other packages like express or socket io works perfectly fine. Any idea on how to install google npm modules on AWS? I tried to write the module in package.json file with the version and zip it along with app.js, files not node modules

```
{
  "name": "dialogflow-aws",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dialogflow": "^0.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

and click Upload & Deploy on AWS ELB console. It turns red. The log as follows:-

```
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Some more logs :

```
39674 silly lifecycle   'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library' ]
39675 verbose stack Error: spawn ENOMEM
39675 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
39675 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:328:11)
39675 verbose stack     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:370:9)
39675 verbose stack     at spawn (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:21:13)
39675 verbose stack     at runCmd_ (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:247:14)
39675 verbose stack     at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:211:7
39675 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
39675 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
39676 verbose cwd /tmp/deployment/application
39677 error Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64
39678 error argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.14.3-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
39679 error node v6.14.3
39680 error npm  v3.10.10
39681 error code ENOMEM
39682 error errno ENOMEM
39683 error syscall spawn
39684 error spawn ENOMEM
39685 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
39685 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
39686 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: How does it fail? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate how you're trying to install them now and what error messages you're getting?